# Replacing values in a column with names (conditional looping)

Tags: r

So I am trying to create a loop to replace row numbers (1-17) with the variable names using R Studio.

For the code this is what I was attempting to do:

```
G1 <- sample_n(G, 100, replace=FALSE, by=V1)
dt  = data.table(G1)
```

```
for (i in 1:17) dt[V1 == i, paste(
 "upps_negative_urgency", "upps_lack_of_perseverance", 
 "upps_lack_of_premeditation","upps_positive_urgency", 
 "upps_sensation_seeking",  "cash_choice_task","BIS", 
 "BAS_Reward_Responsiveness","BAS_Drive", "BAS_funseeking", 
 "ddis_scr_expr_mnrt_allcho", "ddis_scr_expr_medrt_allcho", 
 "ddis_scr_expr_mnrt_immcho", "ddis_scr_expr_medrt_immcho", 
 "ddis_scr_expr_mnrt_delaycho", "ddis_scr_expr_medrt_delaycho", 
 "ddis_scr_expr_mnrt_diffcho", i)]
```

However, when I run it, nothing in my dataframe changes.

This is my first time working with loops so I am a bit stuck on why it isn't changing. I know my other option is using an ifelse statement, however, for this one column I have 17 columns (which isn't terrible to do) but then I have another column with 402 variables so I would love to not have to write 400 ifelse statements.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

http://localhost:20174/session/steep-carp_reprex_preview.html (Attached here is the reprex version)

Comment: You need to assign the result of an operation to either the same variable or a new variable/object. E.g. `for(i in 1:17) ...` will run the expression (...) 17-times. To store the result you need something like `my_result_list <- list(); for(i in 1:17) my_result_list[[i]] <-...` This stores your runs in a list.

Comment: Can you share a full reprex including packages loaded and the G object? Happy to help but the reprex link that you shared is visible only to you (locally).